# ST4 iterate a list with an index

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

So I have a list that is iterated over like so:

```
body(foo) ::= "<foo:{it|<\n><\n><bar(it)>}>"

bar(x) ::= "[<x.key>:<x.value>]"
```

I'd like to use the index.

```
bar(x) ::= "[<i0>:<x.key>:x.value>]"
```

I saw that there is an `<i>` and `<i0>` index token, but I don't understand how it is used, or if it could be used to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the trick is to pass `<i>` or `<i0>` in if you have a function, but i **is** implicitly available inside an iterator:

```
 body(foo) ::= "<foo:{it|<\n><\n><bar(i0,it)>}>"

 bar(i,x) ::= "[<i>:<x.key>:<x.value>]"
```